# It seems that page 32 of "MLaPP" is using notation in a confusing way, I made a little bit enhancement, could someone double check my work?

Tags: machine-learning, probability

It seems that page 32 of "Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective by Kevin Patrick Murphy" is using notation in a confusing way.

> Define the function $F(q) = p(X ≤ q)$. This is called the cumulative distribution function or cdf of X. This is obviously a monotonically increasing function...

Here is the corresponding figure (fig_a).

[image]

I guess **p** denotes probability here.

> define $f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} F(x)$ (we assume this derivative exists); this is called the probability
>   dx
>   density function or pdf.

Here is the corresponding figure (fig_b).

[image]

> Given a pdf, we can compute the probability of a continuous variable being in a finite interval as follows:

${\displaystyle \operatorname {P} (a<X\leq b)=\int _{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx}$

> As the size of the interval gets smaller, we can write

$P(x≤X ≤x+dx)≈p(x)dx \tag{2.21}$

I guess **p** denotes pdf here (fig_b), in opposed to the notation in fig_a, is my understanding right?

so, equation 2.21 is better be denoted as

$P(x≤X ≤x+dx)≈f(x)dx$, where $f(x)$ denotes the pdf, is the modification reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

Textbook authors are not infallible. If you find an error in the text you should send remarks to the author.

- A CDF is *non-decreasing* not *increasing*.
- $p$ of little-x is a probability density function evaluated at $x$, equivalently $f(x)$. I agree we might have preferred to use $f$ consistently, at least for continuous density functions.
- We use little-$p$ or something like it in display 2.21 because it is a function of a non-random value. Contrast with Big-$P$ used to define the CDF in the first display, where the $X$ is the random variable.